# deploying django, error : /mysite.fcgi/ was not found on this server, in shared hosting

Tags: django, apache, .htaccess, shared-hosting

/home/public_html/.htaccess

**.htaccess**

```
AddHandler fastcgi-script .fcgi
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mysite.fcgi/$1 [QSA,L]
```

mysite.fcgi path : /home/public_html/mysite.fcgi

i changed permission to 755(mysite.fcgi)

after executing

**Not Found**

The requested URL /mysite.fcgi/ was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: which hosting are you using?

Comment: justhost.com, shared server account

Comment: did you check this link: https://my.justhost.com/cgi/help/585 ?

Comment: (http://example.com/mysite.fcgi) it shows the file, but when i give (http://example.com/) it says not found /mysite.fcgi

Answer (score -1):

```
AddHandler fastcgi-script .fcgi

<IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
    AddHandler fcgid-script .fcgi
    <Files ~ (\.fcgi)>
        SetHandler fcgid-script
        Options +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI
    </Files>
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mysite.fcgi/$1 [QSA,L]
```

this works for me